# Give IIS 8 Permission to Write to a Network Folder

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, asp.net, api

Created an API using ASP.Net MVC on the .Net Framework. It runs on Windows Server 2012R2. I built a POST Action that uploads an image locally to the server, compresses and renames it. This part works perfectly. I am coming into issues when I then try and move that image to a network file server. The only way I have gotten the move process to work is by granting write permission to Everyone, which of course we do not want to do.

I have tried to assign IIS_IUSSRS write permissions but the only IIS_IUSRS I can apply is to the file server like: FILE-SRVR\IIS_IUSRS and this doesn't work. I think what I need to apply is: API-SRVR\IIS_IUSRS but the file server folder cannot navigate to that location.

I've also tried using the application pool but the file server does not recognize the application pool name as well. Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since I received not even a peep of a response I also posted it on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/968737/give-iis-8-permission-to-write-to-a-network-folder) and got a comment by Greg Askew which turned out to be the solution I needed!

In short I had to give permissions to the machine that was hosting the API.